# Why do I get "'No module named" error with my own package?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a new Django project, but I am failing to get the `makemigrations` to complete, because I get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sare.formats'`. I have had this error before when I forget to install a package required in the code, but this `sare.formats` module is one made by me, in this same project.

I have three apps in the project: `sare`, `formats` and `users`, and the project is named `sare`.
The error ocurrs in the line `from sare.formats.models import System` in my users.models.

In the 'INSTALLED_APPS' section of my settings.py there are, in that order, among other packages:

```
'sare',
'formats',
'users',
```

I would think that because 'users' is included in the installed apps AFTER 'formats', this issue wouldn't exist, so I don't know what am I not aware of. When I type `from sare.formats.models import System`, the IDE autocompletes everything, so I would asume the app is correctly typed and included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
from sare.formats.models import System
```

to

```
from formats.models import System
```